# Unable to fetch elements using get request in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, get, axios

I am new to redux and i want to fetch the listing using GET request API.
The data to be fetched is as follows:

```
[
 {
    "_id": "608bac98e16977cc172a5bf4",
    "username": "saranya",
    "description": "desc now",
    "title": "NaN",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-30T07:07:04.938Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-30T07:07:04.938Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "608bf8c9878cf0b7e85ead9e",
    "username": "saranya",
    "description": "desss",
    "title": "aeaa",
    "date": "2021-12-03T18:30:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-30T12:32:09.618Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-30T12:32:09.618Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "608c0aef6bb6f3d56acd63b0",
    "username": "saranya",
    "description": "desss",
    "title": "aeaa",
    "instructions": "new instruct",
    "time": "1pm to 2pm",
    "type": "want",
    "date": "2021-12-03T18:30:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-30T13:49:35.715Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-30T13:49:35.715Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "608c0df87d8510d6ffcc0157",
    "username": "saran",
    "description": "daaaa",
    "title": "title111",
    "instructions": "instructions for tst",
    "time": "8pm to 9pm",
    "type": "food",
    "date": "2021-05-03T14:01:41.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-30T14:02:32.439Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-30T14:02:32.439Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

The action file authActions.js file is:

```
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";


import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING,GET_TODOS,FETCH_SUCCESS,FETCH_FAILURE } from "./types";

export const getTodos = () =>
 dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: GET_TODOS});

   axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/postad/listing',
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      const data = response.data;
      dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload:{
        data
      }});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch({type: FETCH_FAILURE})
    });
}
```

The types.js file is

```
export const USER_LOADING = "USER_LOADING";
export const GET_ERRORS = "GET_ERRORS";
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = "SET_CURRENT_USER";
export const USERS_ERROR = 'USERS_ERROR';
export const GET_TODOS = 'GET_TODOS';
export const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_FAILURE = 'FETCH_FAILURE';
```

The reducers file authReducer.js is

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING,GET_TODOS,FETCH_SUCCESS,FETCH_FAILURE } from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  todos: [],
  loading: false,
  data: null,
  showSuccessModal: false
};


export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
      case GET_TODOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: action.payload.data,
        loading: false
      };
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
         loading: false,
         error: action.error
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The listings file where the data is displayed is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTodos } from "../../actions/authActions";

import List from '../../components/List';

class Mylisting extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getTodos();
      console.log(this.props.getTodos());
  }

  render() {
        let listings = [];
        if (this.props.todos && this.props.todos.length > 0) {
    listings = this.props.todos.map((owner) => {
        return (
            <List key={owner._id} owner={owner} {...this.props} />
        )
    })
    console.log(listings);
}
        return (
          <div>
          <Dashboard />
                <div>
                        <table responsive striped>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>UserName</th>
                                    <th>Desceiption</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {listings}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
          </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.todo);
  console.log(state.todos);
  const { todos } = state;


  return {
    todos
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getTodos: () => dispatch(getTodos())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Mylisting);
```

The List.js file is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    const List = (props) => {
        return (
    
    
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.username}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.description}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.title}</td>
                </tr>
              
    
        )
    }
    export default List;
```

The App.js file is

```
import Landing from "./components/layout/Landing";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/private-route/PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Postad from "./components/dashboard/post-ad";
import Mylist from "./components/dashboard/my-listings";

import "./App.css";

// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "./login";
  }
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/create" component={Postad} />
            <Route exact path="/list" component={Mylist} />

            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

All the relevant files are defined.The listings file is blank,no data is displayed..How to fetch the data as mentioned earlier using the get request API.Any idea on what is missing in these files?

Comment: Hey! I suppose the problem is in here... you dispatch too many times. 

export const getTodos = () =>
   axios('http://localhost:5000/postad/listing').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      const data = response.data;
      dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload:{
        data
      }});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch({type: FETCH_FAILURE})
    });
}

Comment: So what needs to be done?